# Correcting a perspective of an image based on a reference

Tags: python, image, opencv, angle, perspective

I don't want a code, I want a tip, methodology or reference to develop it. I'm making measurement of objects based on a reference. But sometimes the photographic angle underestimates or overestimates the object's size. Is there an approach to correct the angle (perspective) based on the reference as well? An example of my images:

normal Image:

[image]

Inclined Image:
[image]

The white objetc is my reference.

Comment: you need a foundation in computer vision. your "reference" is too small and generally ill-suited for automatic detection.

Comment: I didn't understand. What kind of detection?

Comment: in short, use rulers or drafting paper or an "art mat" as a background that surrounds the object. your "BBQ" tag doesn't do that.

Comment: if the picture is bad, you're out of luck. imagine people in front of the leaning tower of Pisa. you can't correct that optical illusion given just one picture. take pictures as top-down (straight) as possible and keep a narrow field of view (more distance rather than less).